# Error: Generic type 'Logger<LogObj>' requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: typescript, tslog

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coh6Q.png)
I can't figure out where this error comes from and how to fix it.
this is from a video training material, same code works fine there

```
import { Logger } from 'tslog';
export class LoggerService {
    public logger: Logger;
    
    constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: Instantiate your logger directly with `logger = new Logger();`

Comment: @pzaenger omg it works. is this entry identical to the one in the example?

Answer (score -2):

use command npm i tslog@3.2.2 and all works without generics

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).